# Why am I suspended for 60 days on StackExchange chat?

Tags: discussion

> This user has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 59 days.

Why am I suspended for 60 days on StackExchange chat?
Which site/room's moderator did it?

---

I, on the receiving end, have used "brutality" and other words  accurately to refer to the   behaviors of moderators and elites who have been unhinged in harassing, abusing, and retaliating numerous users, while indulging their own violations, without being punished. As long as no justice is served, I won't be quiet, and neither should you.

Answer (score 11):

It was the U&L moderation team. [You](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53285228#53285228) [have](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=55864462#55864462) [been](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55857369#55857369) [told](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=54552470#54552470) [many](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55857655#55857655), [many](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=51198386#51198386) [times](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=51198013#51198013) [over](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=55985020#55985020) [a period](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=53240920#53240920) of several *years* not to use our chat room to complain about other sites, their communities or moderation practices. You have also been specifically asked to stop using over the top language (examples from the past include your calling closing questions "rape", "abuse", "brutality" etc.).

Despite all of these warnings, you insist on coming back and doing the same thing again. Since you have ignored our attempts to get you to stop, we moved on to the only other tool available to us and suspended your chat account. Please note that this does not affect your ability to use the SE sites, it only blocks you from using the chat rooms for 59 days.

I really hope you will take this time to try and understand why we asked you to stop and change your behavior. We will be very happy to welcome you back if you no longer act that way.

Comment: There has been a lot of hypocrisy going on in the chat room. When I asked about technical questions, I was usually either ignored or directed elsewhere. When I followed others to discuss politics, I  was usually warned and kicked out. Other users including the moderators and elites could discuss anything in ANY topics, and it is always fine!  Where do you draw the line? No moderator is the owner of the chatroom. Last but not least, I am suspended on all the rooms in the entire Stack Exchange network! Is that not abuse of moderation power? Is that not moderator brutality?

Comment: @Tim no, it isn't. Go look up the meaning of the word "brutality" and try and get some perspective. But I am not going to debate this with you again. I and many other users have tried for several years. You asked why you were suspended, and I told you why.

Comment: You have already acted on the past messages that you linked, by suspending my account several times unfairly. What  exactly I have written since then, triggered this two-month-long network-wide atrocity which prevents me in  all the other irrelevant chatrooms?

Comment: @Tim well, just here in the comments, you have already used extreme language like "brutality" (but you have deleted the comment now) and "atrocity" to describe being blocked from chatting on some online chat server. So I don't see that you're getting it at all. The specific trigger this time was [this deleted message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/56133538/history) where you again talked about "moderator and elite brutality". The reason, however, is that ***you keep doing this and ignore all our attempts to get you to stop***.

Comment: When I replied why I couldn't post there, you furthermore help suppressing me, by preventing me in all the other irrelevant chatrooms on the entire network for   two months?

Comment: "hypocracy" is a word that I used to understate the fact that you among others have been violating the "rules" which you and alike have been using to persecute other users including me.

Comment: Hiya, @Tim - CM here... you might remember me from such explanations as [this one on AU meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19306/why-am-i-suspended-from-the-chatrooms-of-this-site-for-almost-a-year/19309#19309). I can attest that the U&L mods acted with great deliberation in coming to this decision. One thing you need to understand is that we have a concept of "breaking the community" - even if no specific action is enough to cause a suspension, a collection of them can show a user as being unable to participate in a way that the community responds positively to.

Comment: This means that we look at all actions as a whole and the past responses to them and judge whether they were sufficient or if more is needed. Your activity in chat over the years has been regularly problematic and causing issues with *many* sites, not only U&L. You've gotten only short suspensions from chat other than the one I removed. Because you've continued to act in a way that shows you're causing discomfort for others in chat, it was determined that a longer suspension was in the best interests of the communities.

Comment: Additionally, as you can refresh your memory, I've already explained that there's no way for a moderator to prevent access by one user to a specific room, chat suspensions are all or nothing, not per site or per room. As such, what you're asking is not possible. You can not be blocked from a subset of rooms only. This was absolutely taken into account when deciding to give you the longer suspension and was determined that it was necessary, regardless, and that many sites may benefit from you having some time away from chat.

Comment: @Catija Please don't keep insulting me.  You only acted that once in my favor, because I exposed it in a public meta post and some moderator helped me to reach you. But the rest? Your long term ignorance of my complaints, and your inaction and encouragement of the abuses are the reason that I and other victims keep fighting. How calm do you want me to be after being tortured for years under your management?

Comment: @Catija So why suddenly jump out to attack me, after ignoring numerous complaints for so long?

Comment: @Catija Are you proud of repeating "You can not be blocked from a subset of rooms only", after I told you it is systematic discrimination several months ago and nothing has changed? (That being said, what about the violation of the same "rules" of moderators which they used to persecute other users?)

Comment: @Tim I think you need to take some time to cool off. Right now you're continuing to do what terdon - and many other mods - have asked you to stop. You're using extremely charged language to describe things to make yourself out as a victim on par with someone being "tortured", "discriminated", and "victimized". These terms are exactly what's causing you to be pushed away and excluded. They are alienating and make people unwilling to help you because they seem too extreme to be founded in actual behavior. None of the mods on this network would do any of those things.

Comment: @Catija Your denial of truth and asking me to be silent is not the solution. How about you and some moderators having some empathy, humanity, justice?

Comment: @Catija since you brought up our last communication, please answered my question again: who reparented my stackexchange chat account to meta.se, to increase my suspension drastically? Have you ever looked into that issue? Have you answered my question? Let me say again: whoever did that is abuse of power and should be held accountable!

Comment: @Catija I was very polite and had been avoiding conflicts for many years, until some users  started to harass me and moderators started to help them abuse me. I am still so and ignoring them most of time. But as long as the unjust suspensions still last and because I have suffered abuses and retaliations numerous times in years, I cannot calm down. No one with feelings can calm down.

Comment: @Catija Again on "You can not be blocked from a subset of rooms only",  remember I told you that when there is room-wise action available, using network-wise action on irrelevant rooms is abuse of power. This abuse needs to be stopped!

Comment: @Catija That chatroom of unix.stackexchange.com has no rules at all. They talk about corruptions in stack exchange (e.g. Monica) and politics (e.g. world leaders), prostate, food, cars and anything all the time. More importantly, the moderators that censored me are not  owners of that room. I had been using that room years before any of them became a user of this site, and no one had ever censored others.